# Can a creature charge through a Prismatic Wall?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

Theoretically, could a character pass through all 7 layers of the prismatic wall in 1 turn? With enough HP and resistances to handle the damage and high saves (with a lot of luck) would it be possible for this character to just charge straight through and make it to the other side?

Comment: What makes you think it wouldn't be possible? Is this about movement (i.e. does the charging creature have enough movement to make it through all 7 walls)? Or is this about whether passing through one wall somehow "ends you turn" or something similar? I'm not seeing your confusion with your proposition...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Yes

Despite the spell creating a "wall", it is not solid. In fact, its made of light:

> A shimmering, multicolored plane of light forms a vertical opaque wall

The spell specifically says what happens when a creature attempts to walk through it:

> The wall consists of seven layers, each with a different color. When a
> creature attempts to reach into or pass through the wall, it does so
> one layer at a time through all the wall's layers.

So if a creature was successful on its saving throws (one for each layer) or just straight-up tough enough, then it would emerge on the other side.

Comment: A Dex-based Ancients paladin running *circle of power* will quite likely pass through with only minor damage. I know because I did it!

Answer (score 2):

### It is possible to charge through all seven layers of a *[prismatic wall](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/prismatic-wall)*

Firstly, I will point out what [PJRZ's answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/171946/35259) points out; that the wall is not solid, but rather made of light:

> A shimmering, multicolored plane of light forms a vertical opaque wall

Therefore, we can establish that passing through it is physically possible, and although each layer describes that various things cannot pass through it, a creature is never described as being such a thing, meaning a creature can attempt to pass through each layer.

As for passing through all seven layers in one turn, the wall is further described as being rather thin:

> [the wall is] up to 90 feet long, 30 feet high, and **1 inch thick**

This implies that, not only is it possible to make it through all seven layers in one turn (assuming, as you state in your answer, that they can just tank the damage and happen to roll well against all of the various saving throws), but that it would be extremely difficult, if not outright impossible, to *not* try to pass through all seven layers, since the entire wall is only 1 inch thick.

Also note that there is nothing stated in the descriptions of any of the seven layers that (assuming you pass all of its saving throws) your turn has to end after you pass through a wall for any reason (any reason not related to failing a saving throw, that is), so each time you survive one layer, you can keep going.

Since movement is only usually divided up into units of 5 feet, trying to travel less than 1 inch in order to pass through one layer but not the other is something that I think it's safe to assume isn't going to happen. It's more likely that you'll be killed or petrified or banished or whatever else the wall can do to you before you make it through all seven layers...